# Uploading image too Google Drive using Google Drive APIs on Windows Phone 7.1 C#

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-8, google-api, windows-phone

I'm new to developing Windows Phone app. Besides, my laptop is so old that I can not develop or use Emulator for Windows Phone 7.5 or higher on it so I have to stick with the old WP7.1

I want to upload a selected image to google drive. I created a button to browse the image and an "image container" to display it after choosing it. Done here with the code below. But after displaying it, I want the upload process to start here too. But the problem occurs at the beginning.

```
    private void browseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        PhotoChooserTask photo = new PhotoChooserTask();
        photo.ShowCamera = true;
        photo.Show();
        photo.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(browseButton_Click_Conpleted);
    }


    private void browseButton_Click_Conpleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        displayIMG.Source = image;

        //It works until now

        //Below is the code I copied from many place that will authorize me to upload to their drive.
        string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                             DriveService.Scope.DriveFile};

        UserCredential credential =
                    GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
                                  .AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
                                  {
                                      ClientId = "MY_CLIENT_ID_HERE"
                                  ,
                                      ClientSecret = ""MY_SECRET_ID_HERE"
                                  }
                                                  , scopes
                                                  , Environment.UserName
                                                  , CancellationToken.None
                                                  , new FileDataStore("Daimto.GoogleDrive.Auth.Store")
                                                  ).Result;

    }
```

It shows much error as it doesn't recognize some of the type or namespace, no `using` is suggested. I create a new project that target WP8.0 with the hope it will recognize all but some still missing like `Environment.UserName` or `new FileDataStore`. I've already added `Google.Apis.Drive.v2 client library` I don't know what I am missing.

My first priority is to develop on WP7.1. I don't want to buy a new phone just because of this. And sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try out the [PedroLamas](https://github.com/PedroLamas/GDrive) sample in order to upload files to `GDrive`?

Comment: Was able to test PedroLamas and successfully upload an image to google drive. Now I'm working on using it in my own app. Thanks for your help, it saves time